# Windows mass data migration utility

Tags: windows, file-synchronization, hard-disk, migration

I am looking for a utility in Windows that will transfer a massive amount of data between volumes (40+ TB, 15 million files). I ideally want something that I can set and forget for a few weeks, and have it generate a list of errors. Of course this has to be a file level migration utility, so that leaves out tools like disk2vhd and the like. And because some of this data has to be mounted on another server, this also needs to work decent over the network.

I have already tried several utilities, but they all have some sort of issues.

- Windows file transfer is decent but it is slow, single threaded,
  stops the entire transfer on a problem, and does not copy long paths.
- While robocopy may work, I am afraid of it corrupting the
  deduplication tables on my drives. (this also leaves out all of the robocopy GUIs)
- Rich copy was probably the most efficient, but it does not copy
  long paths, and often crashed.
- Teracopy also randomly crashes
- 7Zip, surprisingly can copy files, but it is worse than Windows.
- Windows server storage migration I just can't get to work.
- Copy-Item on powershell screws something up because it copies folders to random places

Comment: have you tried [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/)?